# UFT: Not Clicking the Listitem that has brackets in it

Tags: hp-uft

`Browser("Create case").Page("Create case").WebElement("innertext:="&SubCategoryExcel ,"index:=1").Click`

In the above code Webelement is actually a custom drop down. its working fine all the `innertext` that I am passing to it. But when an `innertext` has brackets in it. it doesn't work.
e.g: `innertext:=issues (waiting for communication from primary or secondary decoder)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In descriptive programming the value is treated as a regular expression. Therefore you need to escape special characters by putting a backslash before them
Try the following value

```
issues \(waiting for communication from primary or secondary decoder\)
```